# Battery Life on Ubuntu sucks

Tags: drivers, nvidia, power-management, battery, optimization

Its been a week since I have installed Ubuntu everything is great except battery life. I have installed TLP and Powertop and disabled nvidia graphics yet battery does not lasts more that 3 hours. 
On windows 10 I used to get 7-8 hrs of battery life.

I am using ubuntu 20.04 on Asus K510UQ laptop
Intel core i5 8250u, 8gb ram, nvidia 940mx graphics.

Comment: Are you using the same screen brightness on both, and have you enabled the powersave governor?

Comment: Yes am using the same brightness and no am not using powersave governor, will it decrease performance? I am look for some optimal solution.

Comment: I thought you are looking for a solution that gives you the same battery life (and thus same performance) as you were getting on Windows.

Comment: Performance was pretty good on windows and battery life too.

Comment: So a powersave governor performance in Linux should have pretty good performance, too, then.